# Is switching region considered smurfing?

Tags: heroes-of-the-storm

I am a player in Madagascar and I play on Blizzard's EU servers with an average ping of 250ms to 300ms, a ping that I am used to when I used to play Dota2 on Lux servers.

I accidentally logged in in the US servers once, replaying the tutorials, getting Nazeebo in the welcome chest, not realizing it yet at first, until I pressed <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd> and seen the "Site: US" or something like that. I haven't played online since I know the ping would be disastreous.

But let's assume I dare to play quick match with my level 1 account, considering myself experienced enough to be able to do something despite the high ping (if it allows me to do something though), would that be considering smurfing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [definition of smurfing](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=smurfing) according to urban dictionary is "Using an alternate identity to participate in a system without detection by one's peers" i.e being incognito.

If you would still be linked to your other region then the answer to your question is no, you are not smurfing; otherwise, you are smurfing.